# Backbone not working Node (Headless TDD / Development)

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Vows (BDD) to test MyApp, using Backbone (which needs JQuery). I want to use NodeJS to get headless development, but I'm getting the error A), when I try to execute the code in B). Basically, the JQuery object is not in the scope of the Backbone library. But everything was require'd / imported as in C). Does anyone successfully have Backbone working on NodeJS. I'm aware of the [nodechat](http://fzysqr.com/2011/02/28/nodechat-js-using-node-js-backbone-js-socket-io-and-redis-to-make-a-real-time-chat-app/) (downloaded the code and tried to run it) and [backbone models on server blog post](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/), examples, but they are not working with what I've set up. I'm using Node(v0.5.10-pre) and Backbone v(0.5.3).

A)

```
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined
    at [object Object]. (/js/backbone.js:1082:14) 
    ...
```

B)

```
    var fubar = new myapp.models.Fubar();   // this class already has a url set 
    fubar.fetch();
```

C)

```
    var requirejs = require('js/r.js'); 
    requirejs.config({ nodeRequire: require, baseUrl: 'js', }); 

    var vows = require('vows');
    var assert = require('assert');

    //** Hack to get a Window object for JQuery
    var zombie = require("zombie");
    var browser = new zombie.Browser;
    browser.window.location = "http://localhost:3000";
    window = browser.window;

    //** Hack due to Sinon not being designed to work in NodeJS; putting some stubs to get it working
    sinon = require('sinon');
    var xhr = require("sinon/lib/sinon/util/fake_xml_http_request");
    var fakeServer = require("sinon/lib/sinon/util/fake_server").fakeServer;

    requirejs([ 'jquery-1.6.4', 'json2', 'underscore', 'backbone', '_**myapp**_', ]);
```

I'm assuming underscore is pulled in and used correctly. But I don't think I've gotten far enough to confirm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get this working by having node do the require:

```
    jQuery = $ = require("jquery");
    requirejs([ 'json2', 'underscore', 'backbone', "storydesk", ]);
```

Now, I need to plug in a Sinon fakeServer and see how